# Business integration does not work

Tags: paypal

being a PP developer newbie, I used the PayPal documentation to set up this Business Starter integration:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@mybusiness.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="My product 1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="2" />

<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mybusiness.com/cgi-bin/gk.cgi?ppstatus=ppy" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mybusiness.com//cgi-bin/gk.cgi?ppstatus=ppn" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Back to MyBusiness" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="MyID" />

<input name="submit" type="image" id="submit" src="../pics/b-pp_01.gif" width="200" height="30" border="0"> 
</form>
```

All I get after sending this form away is a blank page with the URL https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks for any help,
Emil

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your button (e.g. you don't specify a total amount; I don't think you are doing what you think you are doing with the custom field; etc.) but to start with: you are giving PayPal two different commands (cmd=_cart, cmd=_s_xclick), and likely neither of them is what you want. _cart is for using the PayPal cart, which is a little-used PayPal product where the cart is maintained by PayPal, not on your site. And _s-xclick is for *secure*, ie encrypted buttons, which you are not doing (your cart fields being plaintext in the form html).

Here's one overview of the button docs:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

... that I hope can help, but ultimately get the reference guide for the *particular* product you are trying to use, specify only that cmd, and use only the field supported by that product. I also recommend using one of PayPal's (non-javascript) button generators to generate your first few buttons, thus guaranteeing that you are getting valid button html, and then modifying from there rather than trying to write from scratch. Helps get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem: What I did comes directly from the guide fro the particular product! Look at this: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/de_DE/html/IntegrationCenter/ic_pps_home.html (in German, sorry). As you can see, the sample code contains both _cart AND s_xclick and does NOT contain a total amount. I feel quite helpless if even the official documentation does not cover the correct procedure.